# Searching for substring "52" in variable value "52/80" doesn't work in TCL

Tags: regex, tcl, regexp-substr, tclsh

The code I'm using:

```
set channel 52/80   
if {![ regexp { ([0-9]+)\/80 } $channel match cchannel ] } {
        puts "Channel regex-ed in \[SLVR\]\[SetAffected_channels\] is: $cchannel\n\n"
}
```

returns error: can't read "cchannel": no such variable

Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: How is that regex delimited, spaces ` ([0-9]+)\/80 ` or are the spaces removed to get `([0-9]+)\/80` ? How do you reference capture group 1 in the regex ? Why is the forward slash escaped `\/` ? What doesn't work btw ?

Comment: If you are referring to <regexp {<space><pattern><space>}, then, I have removed the <space> and tried. Still doesn't help. And, by doesn't work, I mean, when I try to print $cchannel, it says -- "Can't read "cchannel": No such variable." however, return status of regexp{} returns $? as ZERO.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question so leaving a comment instead of an answer, but if your problem is only capturing the 52 instead of all of the fraction I tweaked your regex here https://regex101.com/r/XpkRaI/1

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not matching because of the extra spaces.

```
% set channel 52/80   
52/80
% regexp { ([0-9]+)\/80 } $channel match cchannel
0
% regexp {([0-9]+)\/80} $channel match cchannel
1
% set match
52/80
% set cchannel
52
```

You also shouldn't invert the result of `regexp` in this case; the `if` body script appears to be for when the pattern *does* match...

Comment: Thank you Donal. I just removed the spaces, and it did work!! And yes, also the inverting of results isn't letting if block print it, as regex returns 1 on success.